# How to repeatedly add elements when I click on a button?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that provides some input boxes and a link with text *"Add more"*. Clicking on the link repeatedly adds the input boxes.

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-2" id="repeatDiv"> 
  <label for="total" class="control-label sr_only"><?php echo lang('total_label'); ?></label>
   <?php echo form_input('total',set_value('total'), 'id="total" class="form-control col-md-   4"'.'placeholder='.'"'.lang('placeholder_total').'"'."'");?>
   <?php echo form_error('total'); ?>
</div>

<button class="col-md-offset-2 btn btn-primary" id="addmore"><?php echo lang('add_more_btn'); ? />
```

I want this code to be repeated when a button or the link with text "add more" is clicked.

Comment: you wanna do that with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#addmore').on('click', function() {
    $('#repeatDiv').clone().insertAfter('#repeatDiv');
});
```

Comment: Then remove the "javascript" and "jquery" tags from your question.
Also, not using a client-scriptlanguage doesnt make any sense here.

Comment: so it's not possible in any way ?

Comment: Well you could set a cookie or call the same page with a GET-variable (amount of divs) and iterate that. But that would reload the whole page.

Comment: i like the jquery way but when i repeat the input box .my auto complete doesn't work even i change it's class name .

Comment: Then try to initialize the auto-complete function again after the clone is done.